# What do I import: file_name or class in Python?

Tags: python, class

I have a file named **schedule.py**:

```
class SchedGen:
    """ Class creates a pseudo random Schedule. 
    With 3/4 of total credit point required for graduation"""
    def __init__(self, nof_courses=40):
        random.seed()
        self.courses = {}
        self.nof_courses = nof_courses

        for i in xrange(nof_courses):
            self.courses[i] = college.Course(i)

        self.set_rand_cred()
        self.set_rand_chance()
        self.set_rand_preq_courses()



    def set_rand_cred(self):
        """ Set random credit to courses uniformly between 2 and 6"""
        temp_dict = self.courses.copy()
```

While importing content of schedule do I do `import schedule` like:

```
import schedule
```

If that's correct how can I access the function set_rand_cred(self) from SchedGen class?

Comment: Note that in Python, modules (files) can contain classes, but they are not linked in any way beyond that as they are in, for example, Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do

```
import schedule
schedgen = schedule.SchedGen()
schedgen.set_rand_red()
```

or

```
from schedule import SchedGen
schedgen = SchedGen()
schedgen.set_rand_red()
```

This link provides some information how Pythons [import statement](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Link was helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

The `set_rand_cred()` function is an instance function of the class, so you need to first create a class instance. To create a class instance, you need to be able to access the name of the class. You can do that in two ways.

Here's how to solve the problem using each way:

Importing the module:

```
import schedule

s = schedule.SchedGen()
s.set_rand_cred()
```

Importing the class from within the module and putting the class into the local namespace:

```
from schedule import SchedGen

s = SchedGen()
s.set_rand_cred()
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to first make an instance (using the class's qualified name), then access that function as an attribute of the instance:

```
import schedule
s = schedule.SchedGen()
s.set_rand_cred()
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
import schedule

schedule_generator = schedule.SchedGen()
schedule_generator.set_rand_cred()
```

For more information read the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how you import another module, whether it be third-party or one that you created.  Now, one great thing about python is the many ways you can go with this.  One being, importing the module, retrieving the class from that, or importing the class by itself.

```
import schedule
foo = schedule.SchedGen()
returned_var = foo.set_rand_cred()
```

If you import the class by itself, it's almost exactly the same:

```
from schedule import SchedGen
foo = SchedGen()
returned_var = foo.set_rand_cred()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import schedule
schedule.SchedGen.set_rand_cred()
```

But it's more common to do this:

```
from schedule import SchedGen
SchedGen.set_rand_cred()
```